# Mongo text index, search array of string elements

Tags: mongodb, full-text-indexing

I would like to create a text index in my MongoDB which allows users to search a field that is an **array of string elements**.

For example, my document looks like

```
{
    "stringfield": "hello",   
    "arrayfield": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

and I want a user who searches for "two" to find this document.  Users do not have direct access to the DB.  Currently, pymongo executes their query via

```
our_mongo.find({'$text':{'$search': user_input }}, {'score':{'$meta':"textScore"}})
```

According to the mongo [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/),

> "text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements."

While string values are successfully searched, I could not get my text index to deal with arrays of string elements.  My index was created with this command:

```
db.mydocs.createIndex(
    {
        '_id': 'text',
        'stringfield': 'text', // works
        'arrayfield': 'text', // does NOT work --> EDIT: DOES work
    },
    {
        weights: {
            'stringfield': 10,
            'arrayfield': 5
        },
        name: 'search'
    }
);
```

Comment: Nevermind, it DOES work!  I just misspelled the field name.  :/